# Staff in Staff group starts after the start of the piece

Tags: lilypond

I would like to have a piece that starts with one staff and later has two. I've tried something like this

```
MusicA = #(define-music-function (parser location inTab) (boolean?)
#{ a4 b4 c2 #})

MusicB = #(define-music-function (parser location inTab) (boolean?)
#{ d4 e4 f2 #})

MusicC = #(define-music-function (parser location inTab) (boolean?)
#{ g4 a4 b2 #})

MyStaff = <<
    \new Staff \MusicA
    \new StaffGroup {
        \new Staff \MusicB
        \new Staff \MusicC
    }
>>

\score {
    \myStaff
}
```

I would like to keep the general structure in the code, but I don't know how to fix the part in `MyStaff = <<`...`>>` so that I don't get an error message.

I am aware of [this snippet for adding an extra staff](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/source/Documentation/snippets/staff-notation#staff-notation-adding-an-extra-staff), but I would rather not change the general structure of my code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you attempted to use `define-music-function` here, but your definitions are wrong, because their first argument is not a `boolean`.

Also in your example you define `MyStaff` and then try to use `myStaff`. Lilypond names are case sensitive!

I suspect the message about a missing `}` really means "Lilypond has just got very confused." After a bit of tinkering with the code I got the more understandable message

```
error: wrong type for argument 1.  Expecting boolean, found (make-music ... etc )
```

You can fix that error by changing the argument types from `boolean?` to `ly:music?` but that doesn't fix the staff indentation problem.

But if you simplify the code to

```
MusicA = { a4 b4 c2 }

MusicB = { d4 e4 f2 }

MusicC = { g4 a4 b2 }

MyStaff = <<
    \new Staff \MusicA
    \new StaffGroup {
        \new Staff \MusicB
        \new Staff \MusicC
    }
>>

\score {
    \MyStaff
}
```

it does something closer to what you want:

[image]

However you can't "overlap" the two staves in the `StaffGroup` that way. You probably want to define the staves for the full duration of the piece (using spacer rests where there are no notes) and then use `\RemoveEmptyStaves` or `\RemoveAllEmptyStaves`, and maybe a `\break` so the music on the "second staff" starts at the beginning of a system.

Answer (score 1):

If by "later has two" you mean that the additional staff persists for longer portions of your piece, you can use `\RemoveEmptyStaves`, as has been pointed out in [user19146's answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/58165/staff-in-staff-group-starts-after-the-start-of-the-piece/58167#58167) and is documented in [http://lilypond.org/](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/source/Documentation/snippets/staff-notation#staff-notation-removing-the-first-empty-line). Admittedly the structure of your code has to change moderately, because in a hidden sense, all staves start simultaneously at the beginning of the piece.

```
MusicA = { a1 a4 a a2 a1 a4 a2 a4 a a a a a1 a2. a4 a4 a4 a2 a1 }

MusicB = { b2 b4 b b1 b4 b b2 b1 b2 b b1 b4 b2 b4 b1 b1 }

MusicC = { \clef bass r1 r1 \break c4 c4 c2 c1 \break r1 r \break c c1 c2 c4 c8 c }

MyStaff = <<
  \new Staff \MusicA
  \new Staff \MusicB
  \new Staff \MusicC
>>

\score {
  \layout {
    \context {
      \Staff \RemoveEmptyStaves
      \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-first = ##t
    }
  }
  \MyStaff
}
```